# How to pass a view id in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, android-resources

I’m trying to use Kotlin on Android. I need to pass a `viewId` to a function, so that the function can display a text view.

So, I tried to create a function with inputs: string (to be displayed), and the id (for the location of where it will be displayed):

**Calling:**

```
ShowHello("Hello world", textView.id)
```

**The function:**

```
    fun ShowHello(toshow:String, thisId:id ){ textView.text=toshow }
```

But, the `thisId:id` is failing with “Unresolved reference: id”?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You might use `Int` for res ids like below

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass a resource ID (like a view ID), you can use an `Int` with the `@IdRes` annotation to clarify that only resource (res) ID's should be passed in that position:

```
fun showHello(displayText: String, @IdRes viewId: Int)
```

To understand *why* this works, look into [how resources are referenced](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#Accessing). Each resource ID is mapped to a constant. When you call an ID in the format `R.id.some_view_id`, you get back an integer that references that resource.